# Dask async processing, print results as they arrive

Tags: python, asynchronous, cluster-computing, dask

The following example doesn't work, unless `asynchronous` keyword is not used in `Localcluster`. I would like to control how many processes/workers are used and process functions in parallel and print the results as they are ready. What needs to be changed?

```
import time
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster, as_completed


def wait(sec):
    time.sleep(sec)
    return sec


def main():

    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=2, ncores=2, asynchronous=True)
    inputs = [5, 7, 3, 1]
    client = Client(cluster)
    futures = client.map(wait, inputs)

    for future, result in as_completed(futures, with_results=True):
        print(result)

    client.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, you should remove the `asynchronous=` keyword from your LocalCluster call.  This keyword is used to support async functions, like the following:

```
async def main():
    cluster = await LocalCluster(n_workers=2, ncores=2, asynchronous=True)
    inputs = [5, 7, 3, 1]
    client = await Client(cluster, asynchronous=True)
    futures = client.map(wait, inputs)

    async for future, result in as_completed(futures, with_results=True):
        print(result)

    await client.close()
```

If you don't want to use async-await syntax (which is relatively rare) then you should ignore the asynchronous= keyword.  It probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks! I can call the function with `get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())` and the code ends with a TimeoutError?

Comment: I'm also surprised that the result is 1, 3, 5, 7, because I thought running two workers would deliver 5, 7, 3, 1? How is the distribution done to the workers?

Comment: Why are you using asyncio/tornado style programming?  This is only needed by advanced use cases.  I recommend not using async-await style programming unless you are certain that you need it.  From your description above it seems like this is not necessary for you.

Comment: Efficient distribution of tasks to workers is a very complex topic.  I recommend reading more on the documentation at http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asynchronous.html